# Get device volume - issue

Tags: ios, swift, audio, volume, audiokit

Coincidentally, I encountered some strange behavior from my source code while developing an app:

**I have started an interval that calls a function to output the set volume of the device.**

> When testing the code on a real device (iPhone X), I noticed that the **"value of the volume does not seem to change"** when I press one of the volume buttons.

This was the code I was using:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(
            timeInterval: 0.5,
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(self.getSystemVolume),
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
```

---

```
@objc func getSystemVolume() {
    let outputVolume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
    print(outputVolume)
}
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if this is a bug or not - could be!

However: **Does anyone now how to fix behavior?**  Any help would be very appreciated `:)`

Comment: before executing this function, are u recording voice or something like that ?

Comment: Nope. Tested it without sound in/output - not working in both situations! @ShivamTripathi

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like I've found a working solution on my own:**

I've added those lines:

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    volumeView.setNeedsLayout()
```

---

I got no idea why these lines cause the code to work, but however - now it's working.

```
@objc func getSystemVolume() {
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    volumeView.setNeedsLayout()
    let outputVolume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
    print(outputVolume)
}
```

I really hope somebody could add a comment why these lines fix the code.  `:)`